# Conditional testing in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement

I am trying to conditionally have a `<div>` be displayed if the numeric input is 18 and above and the YO option is selected. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated. Code below.

```
<input type=numeric id=ageSelf ng-model="ageSelf" style="color:black">
    <select ng-model="ageUnit" style="color:black">
        <option selected value=YO>YO</option>
        <option>MO</option>
        <option>WO</option>
    </select><br>

<script type=text/javascript>
  var jq = $.noConflict(); //I am also using angularjs hence the variable
  jq(document).ready(function(){
    jq("#ageSelf").change(function(){
      //conditional for ageSelf
      if(jq("#ageSelf").val >= "18"){
        if(jq("#ageUnit") == YO){
          jq("#over18").show();
        }
      } else {
        jq("#under18").show();
      }         
    });     
});
```

Answer (score 3):

It's [`val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) as it's a function

```
if( jq("#ageSelf").val() >= "18" ) { ...
```

and you're checking strings, not numbers, you probably want

```
var val = parseInt( jq("#ageSelf").val(), 10 );

if( val() >= 18 ) { ...
```

and `YO` should be quoted, both in the HTML and in the JS

```
<select id="ageUnit" ng-model="ageUnit" style="color:black">
    <option value="YO" selected>YO</option>
```

and

```
if( jq("#ageUnit").val() == "YO" ) { ...
```

all together

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $("#ageSelf").on('change', function(){

        var val = parseInt( $("#ageSelf").val(), 10 );

        $("#over18").toggle( val >= 18 && $("#ageUnit").val() === "YO" );

    });     
});
```

Comment: Also YO is a string. It needs to be in quotes. And he's not calling val() when checking for YO